# После обновления WP до вер 4.9.6 выпадает ошибка

Tags: wordpress, запрос

После обновления **wordpress** до вер. **4.9.6**. на месте, где находится `the_content();` появляется ошибка: `Error: The attempt to query the database when not connected` и загрузка останавливается. Перерыл инет, но адекватного решения не нашёл. Может кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какая-то ошибка соединения с БД. Вначале проверьте что есть вход в админ-панель и там можно отредактировать запись, поменять настройки и т.п. Если это не работает, то проверяйте параметры доступа к базе. Так же возможна ситуация, что база повреждена. Для этого войдите в phpMyAdmin с этимим же параметрами входа и там сделайте «оптимизацию» (есть такой пункт) со всеми таблицами.

Если там все ок, то дальше последовательность такая: переключитесь на дефолтный шаблон и отключите все плагины. Возможно проблема в каком-то из них: последовательно включаете и смотрите результат.

Если проблема как-то связана с обновлением wp, то придется откатиться к предыдущему бэкапу и выполнить обновление заново, предварительно переключив шаблон на дефолтный и отключив все плагины (у них может быть конфликт с обновлением или новой версией).

Comment: У него, судя по всему, сайт начинает загружаться, а значит, соединение с базой есть. С остальным согласен.

Comment: Дело не только в соединении. База может работать, но быть поврежденной.

Comment: А я как раз и говорю - со всем остальным согласен.

Comment: При откате на версию 4.9 - все работает. также при этом работают страницы категорий и главная. Проблема в циклах постов. Может изменился какой-то алгоритм/циклы в новых версиях, хотя читал и на рус и на англ. сайтах - ошибка есть, но не нашёл решений.

Comment: На дефолтном шаблоне проверяли?

Comment: Пока нет. Но правильно уточнил, надо поиграться с плагинами. Или как вариант поставить голую установку и натянуть шаблон. Спасибо!